# How to set a base url in Laravel 7.x phpunit tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Trying to set a base url in Laravel 7.x php unit testing. In Laravel 5.8, this is what worked for me:

In tests/TestCase.php

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    config(['app.url' => 'http://' . env('TEST_DOMAIN')]);
}
```

This no longer works in Laravel 7.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    config(['app.url' => 'http://' . env('TEST_DOMAIN')]);
    \URL::forceRootUrl('http://' . env('TEST_DOMAIN'));
}
```

Comment: This helped me with an application that has multiple subdomains running tests in parallel. Thank you!